# Could this (POSSIBLY) run Ubuntu?

Tags: nvidia, ati

Totally yolo'ng this as I know it most likely won't.
I've got an old 2003 / 5 HP laptop with:

AMD Turion 64 X2 1.80GHz 
2GB RAM
Nvidia GeForce Go 6150

I'm currently running Vista w/ Dual Monitor (Laptop screen w/ external nibutir at 1280x1024)

It tends to overheat a lot with Vista if running big tasks, I have no use for it so I want to make it a Linux machine as I'd at some point find something to do with it.

My main machine runs Win 10 & Ubuntu in DB

Comment: I've AMD Turion X2 as well. That has no issues. 2 GB ram is also not bad, but  Nvidia can be pain in the butt . . .

Comment: Barring problems with the video card, should run Xubuntu just ok (I do it with an Atom...). Why don't you just try with a live USB?

Answer (score 1):

The [System Requirements](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) for Ubuntu with Unity are

- 1000 ΜHz processor or equivalent
- 1024 MiB RAM
- 5 GB of hard-drive space
- 3D Acceleration Capable Videocard with at least 256 MB

You computer atually meets also the recommended requirements of

- 2048 MiB RAM

But unfortunately your video card **does not** have dedicated memory (and this  in principle would not be a problem, since it uses shared RAM, and you have enough).
Unfortunately for you its maximum shared memory is 128MB, well below the minimum requirements.

I suggest you to use a [flavour](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/flavours) with less graphical requirements, such as Kubuntu without effects, Xubuntu, Lubuntu, Ubuntu Gnome (Flashback), Ubuntu Mate...